# How to get Bezier points from a curve

Tags: qt, math, qpainter, cubic-bezier, qpainterpath

I am drawing a Bezier curve in Qt using the inbuilt Qt functions:

```cpp
void OpacityCurveWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, width(), height(), Qt::white);

    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    QPainterPath path;
    glm::vec2 startPoint(0, (1.0 - opacityCurve[0].opacity) * height()); // Invert y-coordinate
    path.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < opacityCurve.size(); ++i) {
        int x1 = static_cast<int>(opacityCurve[i - 1].position.x * width());
        int x2 = static_cast<int>(opacityCurve[i].position.x * width());
        int y1 = static_cast<int>((1.0 - opacityCurve[i - 1].position.y) * height()); // Invert y-coordinate
        int y2 = static_cast<int>((1.0 - opacityCurve[i].position.y) * height());     // Invert y-coordinate
        int cx1 = static_cast<int>(opacityCurve[i - 1].handle2.x * width());
        int cy1 = static_cast<int>((1.0 - opacityCurve[i - 1].handle2.y) * height()); // Invert y-coordinate
        int cx2 = static_cast<int>(opacityCurve[i].handle1.x * width());
        int cy2 = static_cast<int>((1.0 - opacityCurve[i].handle1.y) * height()); // Invert y-coordinate

        QPointF startPointF(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
        QPointF controlPoint1F(cx1, cy1);
        QPointF controlPoint2F(cx2, cy2);
        QPointF endPointF(x2, y2);
        path.cubicTo(controlPoint1F, controlPoint2F, endPointF);
```

After drawing them, I am able to move points and their handles save the new points and handles (x,y) position data to a vector.

Based on that data, I try to get the curve y position at given x position:

```cpp
float OpacityCurveWidget::getYPositionAtX(float x) const {
    if (opacityCurve.size() < 2) {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    // Find the segment of the Bezier curve that contains the given x-coordinate
    size_t segmentIndex = 0;
    while (segmentIndex < opacityCurve.size() - 1 && x > opacityCurve[segmentIndex + 1].position.x) {
        segmentIndex++;
    }

   
    // Calculate t, the parameter for the cubic Bezier curve formula
    float t = (x - opacityCurve[segmentIndex].position.x) /
        (opacityCurve[segmentIndex + 1].position.x - opacityCurve[segmentIndex].position.x);

    // Use the cubic Bezier formula to calculate the y-coordinate
    float y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * opacityCurve[segmentIndex].position.y +
        3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * opacityCurve[segmentIndex].handle2.y +
        3 * (1 - t) * t * t * opacityCurve[segmentIndex + 1].handle1.y +
        t * t * t * opacityCurve[segmentIndex + 1].position.y;

    // Invert the y-coordinate
    y = 1.0f - y;

    // Return the y-coordinate without multiplying by height
    return y;
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when I move the x Position of the curve point handle that also affects the y position of curve points in the Qt graph, but in my calculation, moving of any handle point only in x direction does not affect the y position of the points.

This is the QT Curve.
[image]

When i move any handle in x direction it also affects the y Position of curve Points.
[image]

How can i calculate the Y Position at at X 0.5 when total X length is 0 - 1.0 ?

Comment: If "_when I move the x Position of the curve point handle that also affects the y position of curve points in the Qt graph_" is the problem you're trying to solve, please rewrite your post's code to be a [mcve] that shows that off. Right now, your post does not have a self-contained example that shows off the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My QT Curve is fine , but when i use the same points to calculate  via the function which i have written does not account the change in y position of the curve points when i only move the handle in x position.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added more details in my question , please have a look.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The Bezeir Y Position function(getYPositionAtX()) that i have written does not account for X Position change of the handles .

Comment: This is literally how Bezier curves are supposed to behave, though. The curve is anchored at the start and end points, with the curve's start and end tangents "pointing at" the control points. If you move a control point, the entire curve (except for the start and end points, which are fixed) changes shape. If you want to calculate `y` given some `x`, that's covered by several posts already, like [Cubic bezier curves - get Y for given X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879836) and [Finding Y given X on a Cubic Bezier Curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302937)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes it works fine when drawing in QT using  it's bezeir function on the points data but when i use the same points data and try to get the y  position at any given X Position i do not get the correct result , is my Y Position Bezeir function Correct ?   float OpacityCurveWidget::getYPositionAtX(float x) const

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I might have a solution. I don't think you were focused on your real problem and you were occupied by GUI problems(been there, done that).

There is a function in QPainterPath which could maybe help you solve your problem and that is:

```
path.pointAtPercent(percentageOfPath)
```

If you could combine this with some kind of approximation algorithm, maybe you can easily get y value for given x:

From the top of the head:

```
#define APPROXIMATION_TRESHOLD 0.001
bool approximately(qreal inputX, qreal targetX){
     return (inputX - targetX < APPROXIMATION_TRESHOLD);
```

For smaller approximation_treshold you should get more precise y-value.

Then you should call this from your custom curve widget on paint event:

```
qreal targetX = 0.5; // let's say you are searching for x = 0.5;
qreal step = 0.001; // more the zeros, combined with approximation, you get more precise value.

while(!approximately(path.pointAtPercent(step))) step += 0.001;
// while loop will end when it finds your value.
qreal yValue = path.pointAtPercent(step);
```

On the other hand if you really need bezier points, you should create custom GraphicsItem for example inherit QGraphicsEllipseItem and with them control your resulting bezier curve.